# in a 3dmax maxscript make changes in vrml 97 exporter window has to change "Digit of precision = 8"

Tags: 3dsmax

3ds file, i have to export these files in wrl format, i have a script for this 
but the problem is how i change setting in vrml 97 exporter window via maxscript

eg: Digit of precision = 8  by default is 4

Answer (score 0):

Generally settings are saved into the `<max>/plugcfg` folder. Looks there for a file that might store the settings for the VRML exporter. I know FBX settings are there but not sure for VRML for sure.